# MVC - Do I create 'joint' layers when dealing with multiple models?

Tags: design-patterns, mvc, layers

I'm new to MVC and the different layers architecture and this is what I have currently:

2 models: User, Company

2 service layers: UserService, CompanyService

2 interfaces which abstract the database layer from the service layer: IUser, ICompany

2 database layers: UserDB, CompanyDB

Here's the scenario - a functionality that will update both User and Company table in the database. If update company succeed and update user failed, I will rollback the database for the company. Hence I think it makes sense to do this in 1 method.

If so, where do I put this method that handles 2 models? Is it normal to create `UserCompanyDB` in the database layer and `UserCompanyService` in the service layer just for this purpose? And even `IUserCompany` as well.

Since I'm new to everything, chances are, you may think I'm having some misconceptions on the layers based on my current way of thinking? If so I would like to take this opportunity to rectify it too.

Oh and if it helps, I'm mainly trying to follow the example in this link:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaTest#Unit-testing-models

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the MVC design pattern, the Controller part is responsible for translating user actions into modifications of the various Model classes that are involved in a piece of functionality.

There is no one-to-one relation between Controllers, Views and Models. In particular, if a user action requires changes to multiple Model classes, then it is the responsibility of the Controller to arrange that (and also to take care of the corner cases where a failure to update one model must rollback the updates to other models).
To make it possible to handle such corner cases, the Unit-of-Work design patterns can be used. With this pattern, database updates from multiple models can be put in a single database transaction.

Creating a model, service and database class for a feature that needs two otherwise separate models is *not* the way to go.

Comment: Sorry I think I phrase my question severely wrong for the updating database. Here's the updated version as above: If update company succeed and update user failed, I will rollback the database for the company.

Based on this requirement, let's say updating user failed, how do I go about rolling back the company table by simply using `conn.rollback()` if previously I need to exit the database layer and return to the Controller to arrange updating user?

Comment: You would usually use the Unit of Work design pattern for that, or alternatively a framework that supports automatic transaction demarcation (eg Spring).

Comment: @user3373225: I updated the answer